# Count values from one table using two columns in another table

Tags: oracle

I have a problem. I have `table_1 (col1, col2, value)` and `table_2 (col1, col2)`.

I want to count values from `table_1` but only the rows which exist in `table_2`. In both tables `col1` and `col2` are key (not primary).

I've tried:

```
select col1, col2, sum(value) 
from table_1 
where table_1.col2 in (select col2 from table_2)
 group by col1, col2 ;
```

It works , but wrong, select too many rows from `table_1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming no duplicates in the 2nd table, it's straightforward.

ANSI syntax:

```
select col1, col2, sum(value)
from table_1
natural join table_2
group by col1, col2;
```

The "old" way:

```
select t1.col1, t1.col2, sum(value)
from table_1 t1, table_2 t2
where t1.col1 = t2.col1
and   t1.col2 = t2.col2
group by t1.col1, t1.col2;
```

Could have used `WHERE EXISTS` too, I guess.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0da81d/2) for completeness.

Comment: Thx, it works :) now I have to put in PLSQL.

Answer (score 0):

to complete I have to update table_3 (col1,col2, min_value, char)
condition is, when min_value <= sum(value) then char ='Y' (dafault is 'N')

This must works in PLSQL trigger after INSERT many rows to table_1.